# How to start Haxe?

Tags: flash, actionscript, haxe

Should I continue learning ActionScript 3 then slowly adapt to Haxe or just learn Haxe? The problem with Haxe is it hasn't got much support.

Comment: Please take time to read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section before you post another question. (Specifically "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)".)

Comment: also use the haxe mailing list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using OpenFL with Haxe 3, the vast majority of classes parallel AS3 exactly, so there will just be minor syntax differences. You can usually just use the AS3 documentation to understand classes. Haxe really has matured in the last year.

If you are an experienced developer, I would recommend just working in Haxe. However, if you are new to development, setting up a working environment for Haxe / OpenFL may prove difficult. There are a lot of plates to spin and platform-specific issues you may encounter, so be prepared to need help from forums and user groups.

The setup directions are pretty good: http://haxe.org/download

If you do encounter issues, search here for answers (they're most likely there):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/haxelang
https://plus.google.com/communities/100629265342461903925

If you can get up and running in Haxe, your code will be worth more (since you can deploy to desktop, iOS, Android, HTML5, and Flash) and the skills you development will be worth more (for the same reason).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, i'm sorry but what is OpenFL and how can I use it?

Comment: OpenFL is just a collection of Haxe classes that mirror AS3 classes exactly. When you install Haxe, you'll get a command line tool called 'haxelib' and using that, you can install openfl along with lots of other useful libraries (physics, tweening, etc). Here's a guide to get going with OpenFL: https://github.com/openfl/openfl/wiki/Get-Started

Comment: The real beauty of OpenFL is that it mirrors the AS3 classes on non-flash targets as well: cpp, native android and ios, html5/js. This opens a world of multi-target possibilities.